# Read data rows one by one without specifying a range

Tags: matlab

Can I read each record of a dataset without specifying a range, i.e. not specifying `for 1=1:n`?

For example :

```
A = [4  2;
     2  4;
     2  3;
     3  6;
     4  4];
```

I want to read/get rows from A one by one, `A(1,:)` to A`(5,:)`, and stop reading when the last record is found: `A(5,:)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't want to specify some maximum length?

To get the number of rows in a MATLAB matrix, you can use any of these methods:

```
n = size(A, 1);    % Size in dimension 1 (rows)
% or
n = length(A);     % Length of largest array dimension, so needs rows > columns
% or
n = numel(A(:,1)); % Gets number of elements (numel) in column 1 of A
```

Then loop like so

```
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    temp = A(k, :); % Do something with row k
end
```